# Naming conventions for dummy commands

Tags: macros

Are there any conventions concerning the naming of "dummy" commands that are used in a restricted scope for specific purposes?

For example, I am checking if slashes (`/`) are contained inside a string parameter passed on from a user input file. My first instinct was to assign a new command `\slash` with the result but it is obviously already defined.

I could go with the usual `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, etc. but, again, `\bar` already exists.

What are the bests practices for doing so and avoid overriding existing commands?

Comment: if you mean internal use, that is the original motivation for using names involving `@` or do you mean you want to expose the names in the main document, but just within specific environments.

Comment: Or just a prefix.

Comment: \FlorianTheEmperorHelperCommand will definitely be free to use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean to use them only internally. Should I define my commands as `\@slash`? I usually use `\newcommand`, how would that work?

Comment: @Johannes_B However nice, I would like something short that would provide some meaningful insight into what it actually represents.

Comment: `\makeatletter \newcommand\ifslashinside[3]{..} \newcommand\florian@checkslash@i[..]{..} \newcommand\florian@checkslash@ii[..]{..} \makeatother` or something like that? The “user interface” should not have `@` in its name, in this case since you are checking, you can put an “if” at the beginning  the name to be more clear; after that, all the internals could use a prefix, or `@` to separate parts of the name, or a mix or both.

Comment: @Johannes_B Actually, I use `\FlorianTheEmperorHelperCommand` in my code!

Comment: Please note that inside groups you could redefine macros without damage to outside

Comment: It should be noted that you cannot include numbers in a command name unless you use \csname ... \endcsname.  Also, \c@... is used for counters, \l@... is used for the TOC (e.g. \l@chapter), \ps@... is used for pagestyles, and there may be other such conventions.

Comment: @Manuel The names of all the `\if..`-primitives where proper `\else..\fi`-nesting is required start with `\if..`.  When a defining a command where that proper `\else..\fi`-nesting is not required, I'd not give it a name that starts with `\if..`.

Comment: Currently I tend to give all internal macros that are not to be applied by the user directly names containing the same prefix. In my case the prefix contains an acronym denoting the name of the package and the initials of my name, e.g., something like `\newcommand\PKG@UD@CheckWhetherSlash[1]{...something that terminates with \@firstoftwo or \@secondoftwo...}` This way the package where the code appears and - in case there is more than one package author - the person who wrote the code is known.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I definitely like `\ifslashin{#1}{true}{false}` similar to `etoolbox`'s `\iblank{#1}{true}{false}`.